# When an Ecel workbook with LAMBDA function must be saved as macro enabled?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I am looking for the LAMBDA function to replace the below VBA function for evaluating strings:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

I made a minimum function in the Name Manager trying out the LAMBDA fx.

```
ev
=LAMBDA(s;EVALUATE(s))
```

Excel now forces me to save the Workbook as Macro-enabled.
Is this necessary even only with LAMBDA function and not using a VBA module ? Can it be anyhow saved only as .xslx? If not, is there any advantage of LAMBDA still in this case (e.g. Sharepoint usage?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EVALUATE is an Excel 4.0 Macro Function.

Because of this, the file must be saved as xlsm.

The alternative is to create a lambda function to parse formula strings, but that will be very difficult.

Another option would be to use Power Query M expressions and Expression.Evaluate.